# Remove the bottom level in a nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider this input dictionary:

```py
my_dict = {
    'group1':{
        'type1': {'val1' : 45, 'val2' : 12, 'val3' : 65},
        'type2': {'val5' : 65, 'val6' : 132, 'val7' : 656},
    },
    'group2':{
        'type3': {'val11' : 45, 'val12' : 123, 'val13' : 3},
        'type4': {'val51' : 1, 'val61' : 2, 'val71' : 3, },
    },
}
```

I would like to remove the last 'level' (the one that only has numbers), and get something like:

```py
new_dict = {
    'group1':{
        'type1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
        'type2': ['val5', 'val6', 'val7'],
    },
    'group2':{
        'type3': ['val11', 'val12', 'val13'],
        'type4': ['val51', 'val61', 'val71'],
    },
}
```

I am currently doing it by manually looping and so on, but I wonder if there is a way to do it more efficiently.

Comment: What you want to achieve? I could see both are same just differs by their type. One is having dict and another list of keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dictionary doesn't have a fixed number of nesting levels, you could write a recursive function to do it:

```
def stripBottom(d):
    if not isinstance(d,dict):
        return d
    elif not any(isinstance(v,dict) for v in d.values()):
        return list(d)
    else:
        return {k:stripBottom(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
my_dict = {
    'group1':{
        'type1': {'val1' : 45, 'val2' : 12, 'val3' : 65},
        'type2': {'val5' : 65, 'val6' : 132, 'val7' : 656},
    },
    'group2':{
        'type3': {'val11' : 45, 'val12' : 123, 'val13' : 3},
        'type4': {'val51' : 1, 'val61' : 2, 'val71' : 3, },
    },
}

print(stripBottom(my_dict))

{'group1': {'type1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
            'type2': ['val5', 'val6', 'val7']},
 'group2': {'type3': ['val11', 'val12', 'val13'],
            'type4': ['val51', 'val61', 'val71']}}
```

If your dictionary has variable levels of nesting or if you want to drop a specific level, you would need to add a parameter to the function:

```
def stripBottom(d,level=0):
    if not isinstance(d,dict):
        return d
    elif level == 0:
        return list(d)
    else:
        return {k:stripBottom(v,level-1) for k,v in d.items()}

print(stripBottom(my_dict,1))

{'group1': ['type1', 'type2'], 'group2': ['type3', 'type4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give an example of the actual code you are using to change the dict, but likely you will always need 2 levels of looping to iterate over groups, and then types. Something like:

```
newdict = {}
for k, grp in my_dict.items():
    newdict[k] = {}
    for typ, val in grp.items():
        newdict[k][typ] = list(val)
```

One option to be more efficient is to not pre-compute these updted values, but instead when you come to use the 'group' data, wrap the output in `list` at that point. (Though obviously you will still be iterating when the dict is being used, to get these nested dicts).